# How do you use curl to get file contents of URL before AND after posting to form?

Tags: php, post, curl, file-get-contents

Here is my code so far...This will get the contents of the URL after posting in the form....however, I want it to get the file contents before AND after posting in the form using CURL. How can I do this?

```
      $url = 'http://google.com.au';          
      $ch = curl_init();
      $data = array(
      'var1' => 'text1',
      'var2' => 'text2',
    );

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      $result = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);
      echo $result;

      curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply make two requests.  One as a normal GET request, and the second as a POST with all of the post data.

Comment: I already attempted to do that...However, it didn't work. In addition, I don't think it is efficient: http://pastebin.com/UDCc0xvk

Comment: It didn't work 'eh?  Why not?  What did you do to debug the situation?  And, you don't think it's efficient?  I don't think you understand how "before AND after posting to a form" works.  Those are two fundamentally different requests to the server.